# Check if graphs are Eulerian

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, eulerian-path

I've been checking whether these graphs are Eulerian;

[image]

I've come to conclusion that all of them are Eulerian, because they're all connected and all the vertices are of even degree. However, when I checked whether or not these are Eulerian with a piece of software called Graph Theory, it said that none of them are Eulerian.

Is it me that is doing something wrong *or* is it that piece of software? Picture for reference;

[image]

Comment: I'd check your software, I am able to draw an Eulerian path on the first (you should be able to as well) by-hand. And it's an absolute fact that all vertices of even degree (and a connected graph) is sufficient to conclude an Eulerian path exists.

Comment: your computer is dumb. Does your computer understand Eulerian as we do?

Comment: I just thought I was doing something wrong.. piece of crap software, haha

Comment: They're all Eulerian. The one with numbered vertices, for instance, has the cycle $0,1,2,9,10,2,3,4,10,11,4,5,6,11,8,6,7,0,8,9,0$.